# Update Existing database table with new column not working in active android

Tags: android, sqlite, activeandroid

I have the following model in the first version of the database:

```
@Table(name = DBConstants.TABLE_CHATS)
public class Chat extends Model {

    @Column(name = DBConstants.COLUMN_CHATS_CHAT_ID,unique = true,onUniqueConflict = Column.ConflictAction.REPLACE)
    public String chatId;

    @Column(name = DBConstants.COLUMN_CHATS_CHAT_MESSAGE)
    public String chatMessage;

    @Column(name = DBConstants.COLUMN_CHATS_SENDER_NAME)
    public String chatSenderName;

    @Column(name = DBConstants.COLUMN_JOBS_JOB_ID)
    public String chatJobId;

    public Chat(){super();}

    public Chat(String chatId, String chatMessage, String chatSenderName, String chatJobId){
        super();
        this.chatId = chatId;
        this.chatMessage = chatMessage;
        this.chatSenderName =chatSenderName;
        this.chatJobId = chatJobId;
    }

    public static List<Chat> getChats(String jobId) {
        return new Select()
                .from(Chat.class)
                .where("jobId=?",jobId)
                .execute();
    }
}
```

Now i want to update the above model with new column, so i have updated the model class with new column as below.

```
@Table(name = DBConstants.TABLE_CHATS)
public class Chat extends Model {

    @Column(name = DBConstants.COLUMN_CHATS_CHAT_ID,unique = true,onUniqueConflict = Column.ConflictAction.REPLACE)
    public String chatId;

    @Column(name = DBConstants.COLUMN_CHATS_CHAT_MESSAGE)
    public String chatMessage;

    @Column(name = DBConstants.COLUMN_CHATS_SENDER_NAME)
    public String chatSenderName;

    @Column(name = DBConstants.COLUMN_JOBS_JOB_ID)
    public String chatJobId;

    @Column(name = "extra_column")
    public String extraColumn;

    public Chat(){super();}

    public Chat(String chatId, String chatMessage, String chatSenderName, String chatJobId,String extraColumn){
        super();
        this.chatId = chatId;
        this.chatMessage = chatMessage;
        this.chatSenderName =chatSenderName;
        this.chatJobId = chatJobId;
        this.extraColumn = extraColumn;
    }

    public static List<Chat> getChats(String jobId) {
        return new Select()
                .from(Chat.class)
                .where("jobId=?",jobId)
                .execute();
    }
}
```

I'm using Active android for database so i have done the following steps:

1.Update Database version number in the manifest file

```
<meta-data android:name="GC_DB_VERSION" android:value="4" />
```

2.Added 4.sql script file in assets/migrations

3.Added the update query in it.

```
ALTER TABLE chat ADD COLUMN extra_column TEXT;
```

4. Now when I am trying o insert the new column value into database, I am getting the following error:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table chat has no column
>   named extra_column (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO
>   chat(chat_message,Id,extra_column,chat_sender_name,jobId,chatId)
>   VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)
>       10-16 06:54:29.712 16791-16791/com.example.manikanta.navigationdrawerpattern
>   E/SQLiteDatabase:     at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
>   Method)
>       10-16 06:54:29.712 16791-16791/com.example.manikanta.navigationdrawerpattern
>   E/SQLiteDatabase:     at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
>       10-16 06:54:29.712 16791-16791/com.example.manikanta.navigationdrawerpattern
>   E/SQLiteDatabase:     at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
>       10-16 06:54:29.712 16791-16791/com.example.manikanta.navigationdrawerpattern
>   E/SQLiteDatabase:     at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>       10-16 06:54:29.712 16791-16791/com.example.manikanta.navigationdrawerpattern 
>       .......
>       10-16 06:54:29.712 16791-16791/com.example.manikanta.navigationdrawerpattern E/SQLiteLog:
>   (1) table chat has no column named extra_column

Can anyone please explain on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Does `DBConstants.TABLE_CHATS` = `"chat"`?

Answer (score 2):

I have got it solved.

Reason for problem:

The migrations script of active android is not getting invoked on changing the version number in manifest file

Workaround:

I have manually set that database version is changed through Application.class with the following line:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration.Builder(this).setDatabaseVersion(13).create();

        ActiveAndroid.initialize(configuration);
```

I don't know if this is correct way of doing, any better approaches appreciated.